# MobileMapActivity won't run without Google Play Services, which are not supported by your device

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, mobile-application

I create a android app for Google Map Activity. In this, the google cloud project was created and the API was created and its key was brought to the AndroidManifest.xml file. Also API Enabled in Maps SDK for Android. But when running the project it shows as below

[image: 1]

help me make this problem to sole

Here I reinstalled the Google App Services app and tried it. But the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

WHen you create an emulator, each level has 2 versions-  one with Play Services, one without.  You used one without.  YOu need to use one with to use the emulator and maps together.  (Please note that you will also need Google Play Services on the device to run properly in production.  If you want to avoid that dependency, you'd need to use a 3rd party map library).